# Which lib's do i link for fcntl.h and unistd.h in Mingw

Tags: c++, mingw, static-libraries

When #including the `unistd.h` and `fcntl.h` files which mingw librarys must i also link in for correct compilation? also is there any easy way to determine this, or a list of which headers need which libs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both those files are in the c std library. According to this: [Standard C library in mingW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394512/standard-c-library-in-mingw) you need to link against msvcrt.a

Here is a list of files in the c std library: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_POSIX_library