# Does gcc -nostdlib prevent explicit appending of standardlibs?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, mingw

If I call the GCC Linker with the option `-nostdlib` does this override any manual/explicit appendecis of standardlibs?

GCC is 4.8.1 from MinGW.

Example:

```
gcc -nostdlib [MyObjectsAndLibraries] -lmsvcrt -o Outfile
```

Since `libmsvcrt` is a standard library, will it be added to the link process or will it be ignored? I can't find any reliable data on this., this is why I would also appreciate some kind of source to this.

Comment: you can compile in verbose mode with `-v` to see what is being passed to the linker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this context, "standard libraries" means the libraries that `gcc` would implicitely link by default. Libraries explicitely mentioned on the command line will always be linked. In fact, `gcc` documentation at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options even points out that unless you really know what you're doing you should add explicitely `-lgcc` when using `-nostdlib`, as the compiler may rely on some builtins defined in it:

> In other words, when you specify -nostdlib or -nodefaultlibs you should usually specify -lgcc as well. This ensures that you have no unresolved references to internal GCC library subroutines.

Comment: Ok thank you - I know about the `lgcc` which should be mentioned in this case but just to make it clear for me - this means for my example, that the `-lmsvcrt` **WILL BE** linked to my program?

Comment: yes, everything stated on the command line will be linked in any case. `-nostdlib` just says that `gcc` will not add anything beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

Since I found this on Google,

@Virgile's answer is enough, but you may run into linker errors when you link with the style of command you gave. There is two steps to program building: compile and link. You can use GCC to do one or the other or both at the same time.

It is important to note the order of which you specify things. In your build, it may be problematic because your exe never gets linked with msvcrt or gcc. Including two libraries which have potentially the same symbols is also very bad.

Here is canonical build and link statements

```
gcc -g0 -O2 -Wall -nostdlib -c *.c
gcc -g0 -O2 -Wall -nostdlib -o a.exe *.o -lmsvcrt -lgcc

gcc -g0 -O2 -Wall -nostdlib -o a.exe *.c -lmsvcrt -lgcc
```

Here is a good reference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18389266/2262111