# argp library cannot be found in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I created a new c++-project in Eclipse.

This is the code:

```
#include <argp.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

However I get the following compiler-error:

> fatal error: argp.h: No such file or directory

Is `argp.h` part of the compiler? I´m using MinGW-GCC-toolchain in Eclipse.

Comment: No, argp.h isn't a standard header. I found some documentation on it, though: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html

Comment: @chris I also found this doc, but there´s no location to be downloaded or similar. So I assumed it might be part of the compiler itself.

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394512/standard-c-library-in-mingw) MinGW builds against msvcrt, so you'd have to find a port of GNU libc for Windows if you want to use `argp.h`