# Why I don't need the flag -lm in MinGW but in Linux I need that explicitly?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, gcc

If I need to use the math library, I need to add `-lm` when I'm using GCC in Linux. But on Windows when I'm using GCC in MinGW-w64, I didn't use `-lm` and it works well.

I know the reason why it is necessary to link `libm`. But I don't really know why I can omit that in Windows?

Comment: It's just a configuration difference.   gcc driver with Mingw is configured to link in the math library by default, gcc in linux is not.

Comment: @Peter Not precisely. See my answer for details.

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to specify `-lm` on a Mac, either.  There's no harm done if you do, but likewise no harm done if you don't.

Comment: mingw-w64 devs fixed that bug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because, under MinGW, the math functions aren't actually defined in libm. "libm" is an empty library used as a placeholder; the math functions are actually defined in MSVCRT.DLL, [which MinGW uses as its standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394512/standard-c-library-in-mingw).

(The validity of using the system's MSVCRT as a standard C library [is debatable](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140411-00/?p=1273). Nevertheless, that's what MinGW does.)

Comment: Is there a way to use the `libm` optimized math on `MinGW64`?

Answer (score 2):

[In my opinion](http://c-faq.com/fp/libm.html), it is a significant, longstanding bug in the Unix and Linux C library setup that you actually need to use `-lm`.  I'd say you should thank MinGW for fixing this.