# How to find the glibc version for mingw32-gcc-win32 compiler?

Tags: version, glibc, mingw32

How to find the glibc version for x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 compiler ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check glibc version for a particular gcc compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705660/check-glibc-version-for-a-particular-gcc-compiler)

Comment: Its a mingw compiler and with the ablove I am not able to find the glibc version.

Answer (score 0):

> How to find the glibc version for x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 compiler ?

GLIBC does not support Win32, so the answer to "which GLIBC version" is: none.

Instead, a [completely different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394537/50617) `libc` is used.

See also http://xyproblem.info